Unable to reboot ubuntu 22.04
I am using ubuntu 22.04 lts. Recently, I installed lightdm for guest mode. After sometime I want to delete the guest mode, so I searched on internet. I made these changes in this file in terminal
/etc/ect/lightdm/lightdm.config
[SeatDefaults]  
user-session=ubuntu   
greeter-session=unity-greeter  
allow-guest=false

After saving this file, I try to reboot the system, but it showing like this: 
Keyboard Keys are not working. Please anyone tell me how to login to my system. I have many important files in my system.

I don't know how to fix the boot problem shown in the photo. I suggest to boot a live system from DVD or USB memory for creating a backup of your data.
